# NuGet unable to find the version of a package

Tags: .net, nuget

Running the command

```
nuget.exe restore .\MySolution.sln
```

gives this error:

> Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers'.

where the package has previously been installed and restored, but it has somehow become corrupt.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It turns out simply updating the NuGet version via

```
nuget.exe update -self
```

to update from 2.8.0 to 3.4.4 was sufficient, and the package now restores correctly.

Comment: in my case, updating to 5.6.0 helped

Comment: This could work because updating NuGet apparently clears the cache of local packages, but to me it looks like overkill and it might not always work due to no update being available.

Comment: I had to manually download a newer version from [https://www.nuget.org/downloads](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) since 3.3.0 gave an error when I tried to use the `update -self` command; then it started working.  It might be that older versions are loosing support.

Answer (score 36):

I was able to resolve this on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) using the following command to reset my NuGet caches / indexes:

```
dotnet nuget locals --clear all
```

Afterwards I was able to restore my packages successfully:

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: Works great on Ubunutu aswell (with dotnet core 3.1).

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, but I needed to stay with `nuget.exe` 2.8 due to not being able to upgrade the version of .NET Framework installed on our build server (2.8 is the last version that still works with .NET 4.0).

The cause turned out to be having `nuget.config` only pointing to the v3 API. The solution is to add in the v2 API. For example,

```
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget v2" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I was using an Automated Mac build and like you couldnt upgrade `nuget` this fixed my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

When using `dotnet cli` and based on [dotnet restore document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore?tabs=netcore2x), you can use the `dotnet restore` command with some options, such as `-f`, `--no-cache`, and `--ignore-failed-sources`:

```
dotnet restore -f --no-cache --ignore-failed-sources
```

With this command .NET Core does not search in cached packages.

Answer (score 7):

Because I stumbled over this multiple times recently, here is my solution:

1. Go to `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\`
2. Open `NuGet.config`
3. Add `<add key="keyName" value="path to repository">` in `<packageSources>`. In my case it was a network folder pointing to `\\JENKINS\nuGet Repository`

So it should look similiar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="local" value="\\JENKINS\nuGet Repository" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>
    <disabledPackageSources />
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have upgraded my NuGet to the latest version, but I still got the error.

Then I find that, at *Solution Root Folder* → *'packages' folder*, there's `repositories.config` in it, and opening the file, you'll see all `packages.config` that is being used:

```
<repository path="..\Common\Luna.Common\packages.config" />
<repository path="..\Common\Luna.ComponentBehaviors\packages.config" />
<repository path="..\Common\Luna.Data\packages.config" />
<repository path="..\Common\Luna.WPF.ApplicationFramework\packages.config" />
<repository path="..\GuyWire\Luna.Basic.GuyWire\packages.config" />
```

And it is storing the information `1.0.0`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.1.0.4000" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="uNhAddIns" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Because in fact I'm referencing the DLL file by file, so I don't need to get by NuGet. I deleted the `packages.config` file and then the error was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, but all your answers were not helping me.

Then, I found that my clock was delayed (I changed computer that day) and I had not realized that.

This simple correction made it all work normally.
The package version does exist, but because it is considered to be in "the future", NuGet was giving this error that version x.x.x could not be found.

I think this is a huge mistake, because it doesn’t care what time the packages are. If you have a versions list, the datetime it was published is not important.

Comment: I agree they should include some information relative to the error condition. It isn't that the package does not exist under that version, but rather that it is out of date constraints!

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the Nuget cache worked for me.

To do it from Visual Studio just open *Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> General* and click on the button `Clear All Nuget Cache(s)`

Answer (score 1):

In our case we upgraded the NuGet extension in Visual Studio from 3.3.x to 3.4.4.

You can find the update in menu *Tools* → *Extensions and Updates* → *Updates* → *Visual Studio Gallery*.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had "Package source" set to my own specific NuGet server instead of All.

Comment: Is *"All"* literal or not?

Comment: Yes it certainly is.

Answer (score 1):

For me, what solved the problem was running the following command inside the solution folder:

```
nuget restore -NoCache -NonInteractive
```

Comment: What is the explanation? Why does it work? Or just: What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Under *Package Sources*, I had to uncheck *Machine Wide Packages: Microsoft and .NET*